# Why is for an algebraically closed field $k$, $\mathbb{A}^1_k \setminus \{0\} \simeq \operatorname{Spec} k[x, x^{-1}]$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ideals, affine-geometry, localization

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and $\mathbb{A}^1_k:=\operatorname{Spec}(k[x])$ be the affine 1-space. Why is then $\mathbb{A}^1_k \setminus \{0\} \simeq \operatorname{Spec}(k[x,x^{-1}])$ ?

My ideas:
Let $S:= \{ x^n | \: n \in \mathbb{N}_0 \}$. Then $S$ is multiplicatively closed and $S^{-1}k[x] = k[x,x^{-1}]$.
The prime ideals of the localisation of $k[x]$ at $S$ are exactly the prime ideals of $k[x]$ which don't intersect $S$. So $(0)$ and $(x-a)$ for $a \neq 0$. Is this what is meant by $\mathbb{A}^1_k \setminus \{0\}$ ?

Comment: This makes sense to me. If you look at group schemes, we have the one-dimensional additive group scheme $\mathbb{G}_a = Spec(k[x])$ whose $k$-points are the additive group $(k,+)$, and the one-dimensional multiplicative group $\mathbb{G}_m = Spec(k[x,x^{-1}])$ whose $k$-points are the multiplication group scheme $(k^\times,\cdot)$, which is just $k-\{0\}$. (I'm learning this stuff too so it's possible that I'm using these words wrong)

Comment: 1. Please use `$\operatorname{Spec}$` to format $\operatorname{Spec}$. 2. You may have a potential imprecision when defining $S$ - you probably want $S=\{x^n\mid n\in\Bbb Z_{\geq 0}\}$, but maybe that's what you've written and I'm reading it wrong.

Comment: Sure, I will do that in the future. And yes, you are right that is what I meant. But I think I used the wrong notation. Thank you ! But I meant $\{x^n | n \in \mathbb{N}_0 \}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really, this is a matter of definitions. If we regard $\Bbb{A}^1_k$ as the set $k$ with its Zariski topology, then $\Bbb{A}^1_k\setminus \{0\}$ is an open subset $U$ of $\Bbb{A}^1_k$ and the regular functions on $U$ are by definition quotients $f(x)/g(x)$ such that $f,g\in k[x]$ and $g(p)\ne 0$ for all $p\in U$. In particular, the only admissible $g(x)$ are of the form $ax^n$ for $a\in k$ and $n\in \Bbb{N}$. So, $\mathcal{O}(U) = k[x,x^{-1}] = k[x]_x$.

The scheme $\Bbb{A}^1_k$ is defined to be $\mathrm{Spec}\:k[x]$. Then by $\mathbb{A}^1_k\setminus \{0\}$ you might mean $\mathrm{Spec}\:k[x]\setminus \{(x)\}$, where $(x)$ is the ideal of functions corresponding to the closed point $0$ in the classical picture. In that case, note that $\{(x)\}$ is closed and so $\mathrm{Spec}\:k[x]\setminus \{(x)\}$ is open, defined to be the complement of $V(x) = \{(x)\}$. In particular, by the definition of the sheaf of functions on an affine scheme, the functions are $k[x]_{x} = k[x,x^{-1}]$.

In short, after suitable interpretation the answers are the same. You just need to be careful what language you mean.

Note that the classical variety $\mathbb{A}^1_k\setminus \{0\}$ in the first paragraph is *not* the same space as $\mathrm{Spec}\:k[x,x^{-1}]$ because the latter space has a generic point $\xi$ corresponding to the zero ideal which is dense in the whole space. That point is not closed, so the spaces are not even homeomorphic. The latter is the soberification of the former.